# ASP.NET MVC file upload working on local build, NOT working after deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

This code for uploading image file is working fine when built on localhost. But upon deployment, it is not working and not giving any error.

I tried changing the imagePath from `/Content/Images/Items/` to `~/Content/Images/Items/` and `Content/Images/Items/`. Still no solution.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddProduct(ProductDisplay productDisplay,HttpPostedFileBase upload)
{
    bool isSaved = false;
    string fileName = string.Empty;
    string imagePath = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        if(upload!=null && upload.ContentLength>0)
        {
            fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName);
            imagePath = "/Content/Images/Items/" + fileName;
            upload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(imagePath));
        }
        else
            imagePath = "/Content/Images/Items/" + "NoImage.jpg";
        productDisplay.ImagePath = imagePath;
        ProductMangementBL balProduct = new ProductMangementBL();
        isSaved = balProduct.AddProduct(productDisplay);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        isSaved = false;
    }
    return RedirectToAction("ProductList", new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Product", action = "ProductList", Id = productDisplay.CategoryID }));
}
```

Comment: is there an exception being thrown? I only see you setting a boolean in your catch block - don't see any logging, so any exception thrown is being swallowed and helpful information telling what went wrong is being lost. without knowing the exception, I doubt you will find a solution.

Comment: Should'nt it be `\ and a @` sign at the beginning?

Comment: The issue was with the application pool permission. Thanks to all for putting there thoughts here.

Answer (score 3):

Some things to check:

```
var mapped = Server.MapPath(imagePath);
if (File.Exists(mapped))
{
  //
}
else
{
  throw new FileNotFoundException(imagePath);
}
```

In other words, the image may not be there.

Answer (score 2):

Might want to check what your application pool is running as, and if it has permissions to write files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create testProductAdd action and corresponding test view.

Then try to run just this code without any exception handling.

```
fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName);
imagePath = "/Content/Images/Items/" + fileName;
upload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(imagePath));
```

This way you can find out where the problem is.

Comment: explain why it will help him find the problem.

Comment: 1) You don't experiment with the production code. 2) This way you just test file upload and file save. No other logic affects this code which can confuse you.

Comment: ^^ that doesn't explain why it will help solve his problem. tbh what he really needs is a logging function in his exception handler, since right now the exception is being swallowed. like it or not, he already is experimenting with production code since he doesn't know what the problem is and can't replicate it locally.

Comment: You can create test view and experiment with it as much as you want in the production sever. It won't affect actual code. The point is. You use production environment.

Answer (score 0):

Add a logging function to your exception handling, since right now you are just setting a boolean and never using it again before exiting the function, and so losing the information in the exception.

Write the exception to a text file and it will provide you with the cause of the error and guide you to the solution.

You can use something as simple as a `StreamWriter` to write the exception to a text file.

For instance:

```
try
{
    if(upload!=null && upload.ContentLength>0)
    {
        fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName);
        imagePath = "/Content/Images/Items/" + fileName;
        upload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(imagePath));
    }
    else
        imagePath = "/Content/Images/Items/" + "NoImage.jpg";
    productDisplay.ImagePath = imagePath;
    ProductMangementBL balProduct = new ProductMangementBL();
    isSaved = balProduct.AddProduct(productDisplay);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\log.txt", true))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

This will write the error message and stacktrace to the text document "log.txt" in your C: drive.

Answer (score 0):

- Assign the "Network Service" account to the target folder.
- Then give the "Network Service" Full Permissions (not secure).
- Then move files to another folder (Alternative option).

More secure option:

- Upload files to another server
- Scan the files with anti virus
- Then Pull the files into the production server using third party software like MoveIt
- http://www.ipswitchft.com/moveit-managed-file-transfer

Answer (score 0):

It might be corresponding folder don't exists on your server.

Consider check folder existence before saving the file:

```
string directory=Server.MapPath("/Content/Images/Items/");
if(!Directory.Exists(directory))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
}
upload.SaveAs(Path.Combine(directory,fileName));
```